# Extending a field under some constraints

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $G$ be a given finite group. Is there a way to extend the field $K$ such that for the extension $L\geq M\geq K$ we have that  $L/M$ is Galois and it's Galois group $Gal(L/M)$ is isomorphic to $G$ ? If there is, along which lines does the proof run ?

(I didn't manage to come up with a proof - nor with a counterexample to this question)

Comment: Is $K \subset L$ just an arbitrary field extension?

Comment: Just to clarify, you are asking: given a field $K$, does there exist an extension $M$ of $K$ and a Galois extension $L/M$ such that $\mathrm{Gal}(L/M)$ is isomorphic to a *given* finite group?

Comment: $L = M = K\phantom{}$?

Comment: @KeenanKidwell exactly! Ok, by looking at the comments, it seems that I should have been more precise. sorry

Comment: @JacobSchlather Well...yes, under the constraints I listed

Comment: @HansGiebenrath I don't think that will work (see Keenan Kidwells comment)

Comment: Well, it is well known, and not particularly difficult to prove, that any finite group happens as a Galois group of some field extensions *but this is so as long as we do not fix the ground field*, as you want. In this case, I can't say for sure.

Comment: @user47580: Now we've established what you're actually asking, you should edit your question to reflect this.

Comment: Are we assuming that $M/K$ is finite?

Comment: @ChrisEagle No. I edited the question.

Comment: @DonAntonio Hm...Could you give me (a reference of) that proof ? Maybe I can draw some inspiration from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking if for a field $K$ does there exist an extension $M$ such that the inverse Galois problem is solved over $M$. The inverse Galois problem being showing that for every finite group $G$ there exists a Galois extension $L$ of $M$ such that $\mathrm{Gal}(L/M)$. This is a difficult question. In the case that $K$ is characteristic $0$ the answer is yes. You can set $M=\overline{K}(t)$ for which the problem is solved. There are some results over the case that characteristic is $p$ but I don't understand them, or the previous result honestly.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n$ be large enough that $G$ embeds in $S_n$. Let $L$ be the field of rational functions over $K$ in $n$ variables. Let $E$ be the subfield of $L$ consisting of symmetric rational functions. Then $L/E$ is Galois with Galois group $S_n$. Consider a copy of $G$ in the Galois group, and let $M$ be its fixed field. By the fundamental theorem, $L/M$ is Galois with Galois group isomorphic to $G$.